# Novel called "(Something) World". Nanotechnology / world-wide speed limit displayed in the sky, enforced by satelite weapons

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, science, nanotechnology

The protagonist awakes to find himself with amnesia, and the story is his journey to self-discovery. Two features of the story are nanotechnology in his body, and a world-wide speed limit, displayed in the sky, that is slowly being lowered, enforced by weaponized sattelite.

The world is also divided into zones, with different rules for each zone....not too sure about that last part. The title is two words, "*(Something)* World", I think.

Comment: Had to think of [this question/answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37907/novels-based-on-humanity-fleeing-from-earth-and-regressing-to-a-pre-industrial) when I read yours - maybe you'd like it as well.

Answer (score 7):

"[Quad World](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2372613.Quad_World)", by Robert Metzger....a good read!

> *"but as you well know, time runs very short." He look a quick glance over his shoulder and looked up into the sky.
>
>   I also looked: 23.
>
>   It had dropped by another three kilometers per hour. I didn't know if Napoleon believed the Speed Limit story that Joan had told me, but he obviously thought those numbers in the sky were going to translate into something very real happening down here on the ground.*

Comment: I looked at [this book's page on amazon](http://amzn.com/1585866180) and didn't see anything like the description in the question.  Could you add some detail to your answer to show the connection?

Comment: Similarly, the [goodreads page](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2372613.Quad_World) and the comments make it sound very different from what you've described.

Comment: I've found a copy on [google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c2IR9hyxGAQC&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=%22I+didn%27t+know+if+Napoleon+believed+the+Speed+Limit+story%22&source=bl&ots=aQYkVe7cC2&sig=QfFlRH-FoF6DKl4MDy2Vf7lHbb0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikyOP7i5jSAhUrK8AKHaZ0At0Q6AEIGjAA#v=snippet&q=speed%20limit&f=false). There are repeated mentions of a "speed limit" being displayed in the sky and the "eyes of God" that punish anyone who exceeds that speed.